# "User account does not exist in organization" when using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-identity

I have validated that my user is in the directory associated with this tenant id, as well as added as a user to the registered application associated with this clientid and I still get the following error:

'AuthenticationRequiredError: invalid_request: 700056 - [2023-12-10 22:03:29Z]: AADSTS700056: User account does not exist in organization.

```
import {UsernamePasswordCredential} from '@azure/identity';
import {TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider} from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/authProviders/azureTokenCredentials/index.js';
import { Client } from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client';

const credential = new UsernamePasswordCredential(
    '9d1d3c46-2270-4b75-9647-04a2e0f4995e',
    '9fbaff4b-0387-4695-ae25-2da4bbceed76',
    'casanovajordan123@gmail.com',
    '*******'
  );
  
  // @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/authProviders/azureTokenCredentials
  const authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider(credential, {
    scopes: ['User.Read'],
  });
  
 const graphClient = Client.initWithMiddleware({ authProvider: authProvider });



const calendar = {
    name: 'test'
};

await graphClient.api('/me/calendars').post(calendar);
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: ROPC flow doesn't allow support personal accounts. The personal accounts which are invited cannot use ROPC flow. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth-ropc) . Only work accounts are supported.

I generated access token via ROPC via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:password
scope:user.read
username:rukmini@gmail.com
password:***
client_id:ClientID
```

[image]

**To resolve the issue**, either make use of work/school account or switch the authentication flow and make use of Authorization code flow.

To fetch the calendar details, create an Azure AD application and grant **`Calendars.Read`** API permission:

[image]

Generate **auth-code** by using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=Calendars.Read
&state=12345
```

[image]

[image]

Now generate **access token** by using below parameters:

[image]

***I am able to fetch the calendar details successfully:***

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar
```

[image]

You can make use of below c# code:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var scopes = new[] { "Calendars.Read" };
var tenantId = "common";
var clientId = "ClientID";
var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
var authorizationCode = "code";

var options = new AuthorizationCodeCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var authCodeCredential = new AuthorizationCodeCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, authorizationCode, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authCodeCredential, scopes);
var result = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.GetAsync();

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Reference:**

[Get calendar - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Thank you very much Rukmini. I have everything working, but I am now getting the following error: "AuthenticationRequiredError: invalid_grant: 70000 - [2023-12-14 05:17:27Z]: AADSTS70000: The provided value for the 'code' parameter is not valid. Trace ID: 
2c881645-e511-4756-922c-0d52d1771001 Correlation ID: 65b6a746-3197-4f9b-bb78-80fed6b2a2f3 Timestamp: 2023-12-14 05:17:27Z - Correlation ID: 65b6a746-3197-4f9b-bb78-80fed6b2a2f3 - Trace ID: 2c881645-e511-4756-922c-0d52d1771001"

Comment: How are you generating code?

Comment: Copy only the [**code value**](https://i.imgur.com/FL8Kt9g.png) and note that code cannot be reused.

Comment: Thank you for your help Rukmini. As far as I can tell I've done all of this. Refer to my latest answer above.

Comment: Yes. I used that code verbatim, just swapping in my client id.

Comment: I am wondering if it is an issue on the app registration side at this point, that is causing a bad code to generate.

Comment: Is the clientID you are passing in the authcode request matches with the c# code and portal?

Comment: It is still not working.

Comment: Can you paste your endpoint to generate code?

Comment: Yes. Client Id matches. I am using TypeScript not C#. Refer to my above answer to see the exact code. It mirrors your C# code.

Comment: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?&client_id=fbc9f4f3-88ba-4db4-b931-67fa00cfee73&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&response_mode=query&scope=Calendars.Read&state=12345

Comment: You are passing `'M.C104_BL2.2.873f4e8e-f1ab-f454-f00a-bf3ea97fb348&state=12345'` remove the `$state=12345` and pass only `M.C104_BL2.2.873f4e8e-f1ab-f454-f00a-bf3ea97fb348`

Comment: Now try running the code using only code value and check

Comment: Amazing one step closer. Error now is as follows:
'AuthenticationRequiredError: invalid_grant: 70000 - [2023-12-14 14:23:26Z]: AADSTS70000: The request was denied because one or more scopes requested are unauthorized or expired. The user must first sign in and grant the client application access to the requested scope. Trace ID: 176ae463-9a7e-4562-9121-fdf82c539800 Correlation ID: 8a40beb6-ee6a-4ff7-a13b-ff2c38f3f4bb Timestamp: 2023-12-14 14:23:26Z - Correlation ID: 8a40beb6-ee6a-4ff7-a13b-ff2c38f3f4bb - Trace ID: 176ae463-9a7e-4562-9121-fdf82c539800'

Comment: Did you grant `Calendars.Read` delegated API permission in your Azure AD application? check my answer

Comment: Yes I did. As well as Calendars.ReadWrite

Comment: I also added the corresponding application API permissions just in case.

Comment: Can you paste the screenshot of the API permissions??

Comment: And did you grant Admin consent to the API permissions?

Comment: yes, and yes. Screenshot added to latest answer.

Comment: Can you regenerate the authcode and execute the TypeScript program?

Comment: I've done so several times now

Comment: Can you try modifying the  program using this request https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request

Comment: Done. screenshot added to my answer. I really appreciate your time. This is driving me crazy. I am very new to this lol.

Comment: I feel there is some issue with the code as the config part looks good

Comment: Check this sample code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/typescript?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=4

Comment: Ok. I will look more this evening. Thank you.

Comment: The issue in the end was again due to using my personal account. I leveraged my work account and was able to call the api without issue! Thank you again for your support.

Answer (score 0):

After realizing that ROPC flow would never work for my account type, I adopted the authorization code flow as follows.

First I got the authorization code using the following:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?&client_id=fbc9f4f3-88ba-4db4-b931-67fa00cfee73&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=Calendars.Read&state=12345
```

[image: jwt authorization code shown here]

Then I ran the following code with that auth code:

```
import { AuthorizationCodeCredential } from "@azure/identity";
import { TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider } from "@microsoft/microsoft- 
graph-client/authProviders/azureTokenCredentials/index.js"
import { Client } from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client';

const credential = new AuthorizationCodeCredential(
'common',
'fbc9f4f3-88ba-4db4-b931-67fa00cfee73',
'****~Q3hJRe5Liuo6wDs83Lw_Opo5ne5ad85afF',
'M.C104_BL2.2.873f4e8e-f1ab-f454-f00a-bf3ea97fb348&state=12345',
'https://jwt.ms',
 );

  // @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/authProviders/azureTokenCredentials
 const authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider(credential, {
scopes: ['Calendars.Read'],
 });

  const graphClient = Client.initWithMiddleware({ authProvider: authProvider });

  const calendar = {
name: 'test'
};

 await graphClient.api('/me/calendars').post(calendar);
```

This cause the following error:
"AuthenticationRequiredError: invalid_grant: 70000 - [2023-12-14 05:17:27Z]: AADSTS70000: The provided value for the 'code' parameter is not valid. Trace ID:
2c881645-e511-4756-922c-0d52d1771001 Correlation ID: 65b6a746-3197-4f9b-bb78-80fed6b2a2f3 Timestamp: 2023-12-14 05:17:27Z - Correlation ID: 65b6a746-3197-4f9b-bb78-80fed6b2a2f3 - Trace ID: 2c881645-e511-4756-922c-0d52d1771001"

I've managed to get it to work, after realizing I was passing the auth code with the state query param at the end. I now get the following error:

'AuthenticationRequiredError: invalid_grant: 70000 - [2023-12-14 14:36:37Z]: AADSTS70000: The request was denied because one or more scopes requested are unauthorized or expired. The user must first sign in and grant the client application access to the requested scope. Trace ID: 8b086326-7e1d-4a4e-96d5-cbc935f54900 Correlation ID: 6cdf9f0b-affe-4443-8a71-7d5b78f7d18b Timestamp: 2023-12-14 14:36:37Z - Correlation ID: 6cdf9f0b-affe-4443-8a71-7d5b78f7d18b - Trace ID: 8b086326-7e1d-4a4e-96d5-cbc935f54900'

My app registration permissions are as follows:

[image: App permissions]

I've changed up the code a little and get the following:

[image: javascript error]